# How does workbooks.open in vba differ from opening the file manually?

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I have a .clb file that can be opened with excel through windows explorer with no issues. When I try to open the same .clb file through VBA with workbooks.open the dates in the file get messed up.
For example 11/05/16 becomes 5/11/16. I must point out that this is not a format change, the format stays the same (d/mm/yy) but the date goes from 11th Mar to 5th Nov.
I assume the issue has something to do with format confusion somewhere along the way because the dates that cannot be confused with US format like 18/06/16 for example get converted to string format for some reason.
These issues do not occur when vba is not used to open the workbook and I have reduced my code down to a single line to make sure there are no unwanted interactions:
 `Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\C_001S01.clb"`
and the issue still persists.
Is there some other function I can use to open the .clb in vba that will not mess with the dates? or a way to prevent workbooks.open from messing them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `.clb` format is a text file, you need to use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method (instead of `Workbooks.Open`), and specify your preferences for the delimiters, date formats and other settings.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. It looks like you can't specify d/m/y 12:59 as the date type but I can use string format and then parse it later on.